# Why does the "contains" method on "Option" use a second type with lower bound instead of an "Any" type?

Tags: scala

I was looking through the Option class in Scala and and came across the contains method:

```
final def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean
```

Option is covariant so I understand that it can't just use A as the type of elem. However, given that the type A1 is never used, why can't the method just be this:

```
final def contains(elem: Any): Boolean
```

Is it just a style thing or have I missed something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason, it is just an oversight. Actually, it is not even the only one. [`Either.joinRight`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/da49d9a00ec373a0e7f2ffe946a897a65c9b0741/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L134) for example also contains unnecessary lower bounds. But because removing them would mean to break source and binary compatibility it didn't happen so far.

Answer (score 2):

It is directly related to the fact that `Option` is covariant and in fact, required in order for the types to match up.

```
class Foo(x: Int)
object Bar entends Foo(0)

def foo(t: Option[Foo]) = t contains (new Foo(2))
```

I can actually pass in a type of `Option[Bar.type]` and it will "work" because `Bar` is a `Foo` and type boundedness of the type requires that it also accept types that are super types of the parameterized type `A`.

```
val res = foo(Some(Bar))
>> res0: Boolean = false
```

Note that the above is actually calling `contains` on an instance of a `Option[Bar.type]`. Hence, the `[A1 >: A]`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer completely but from my experimentation if the contains method parameter has type Any, foo(Some(Bar)) would work as well.

Comment: as can be seen if you add these:
abstract class NOption[+A] {
  def x:A
  def contains(elem: Any): Boolean = x == elem
}
case class NSome[+A](x:A) extends NOption[A]
and update your code to use NOption and NSome

Comment: I agree with @Boomah. Since `A1` must be a supertype of `A`, you can pass in anything for `A1`, and it could just as well be `Any`.